# click event not firing in antd menu item

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, antv

I'm creating a dynamic menu using vue3 and antdv

**MenuItem.vue**

```js
<template>
  <slot name="menu-item" :items="[data]" />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
export default defineComponent({
  props: ['data']
})
</script>
```

**MenuGroup.vue**

```js
<template>
  <a-sub-menu>
    <template #title>
      <component v-if="data.icon" :is="data.icon"></component>
      <span>{{ data.label }}</span>
    </template>
    <slot name="menu-item" :items="data.items" />
  </a-sub-menu>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
export default defineComponent({
  props: ['data']
})
</script>
```

**Layout.vue**

```js
     <a-menu theme="dark" mode="inline" v-model:selectedKeys="selectedKeys">  
        <component v-for="block in menu" :key="block.key" :is="block.component" :data="block">
          <template v-slot:menu-item="{ items }">
            <a-menu-item v-for="item in items" :key="item.key" @click="handleMenuClick">
              <component v-if="item.icon" :is="item.icon"></component>
              <span>{{ item.label }}</span>
            </a-menu-item>
          </template>
        </component>
      </a-menu>
```

edit:
putting a normal menu item inside the menu will trigger the click event

```js
     <a-menu-item @click="handleMenuClick">
          <span>title</span>
        </a-menu-item>
```

my items array:

```js
     [
  {
    key: 'keyA',
    label: 'labelA',
    icon: HomeOutlined,
    component: MenuItem,
    route: '/someroute'
  },
  {
    key: 'keyB',
    label: 'labelB',
    icon: HomeOutlined,
    component: MenuGroup,
    items: [
      {
        key: 'keyc',
        label: 'labelc',
        icon: ToolOutlined,
        route: '/route-sample'
      }
    ]
  }
```

The code looks like is working, but when I click on the submenu **keyc** the function **handleMenuClick** is called, by clicking on **keya** nothing happen....what I'm doing wrong?

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-johnson-v2s8s?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ant design implements own click handler that will override whatever you have setup when it is available.

You're likely better off using the `onClick` in the `<a-menu>` or `onTitleClick` for `<a-sub-menu>` items

Comment: the strange thing is  that if i put inside the menu a normal a-menu-item it will trigger the click event      <a-menu-item @click="handleMenuClick">
          <span>title</span>
        </a-menu-item>